# Can I embed social media links into a oft file?

Tags: templates, plugins, outlook

Trying to create an outlook template file and was wondering if I Can  embed social media links into a oft file?

Answer (score 0):

How is a social media link different from a regular HTML link? You can create a template with HTML body populated with any content, including links.